# UWP GridView click blank to clear selected

Tags: c#, uwp

Thanks in advance.

I think it is a simple question, but I have No idea.

In MianPage, I have a girdview.

and I declare `Itemclick` method.

```
IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
IsRightTapEnabled="True"
ItemClick="girdView_ItemClick"
RightTapped="girdView_RightTapped"
```

in ItemClick, I tried this:

```
private async void girdView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var gridView = sender as GridView;
        if (e.ClickedItem == gridView.SelectedItem)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            gridView.SelectedItem = null;
        }
    }
```

when I click a same item, it can be cancel. but I also want to click blank area to cancel selected.

I tried :

```
if (e.ClickedItem == gridView.SelectedItem || e.ClickedItem == null)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            gridView.SelectedItem = null;
        }
```

but, when I click blank area, it **NOT** invoke `girdView_ItemClick` method. So it is useless.

thanks, anybody have ideas?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @aneeshjose sorry for that, it's c#, it's weird, I choose c# and it change to c...

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the UI..? it will helps us understand your problem better.. also,"I also want to click blank area to cancel selected" - by this,do you mean you want the selection to go away whenever you click on anything else other than you gridview when it is in selected state ?

Comment: @Pratyay emm.. such as I click a item in gridview, the item will be selected, then I click a blank area,  I want the selected item be not selected.... I'm not good at English, do you understand me? Thanks .

Comment: Did you mean click any places in the app UI except `GridView`? Any other elements on the page?

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT no, I mean, when I click blank area in gridview , gridview selected = null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I mean, when I click blank area in gridview , gridview selected = null

In this case, you could try to subscribe the [`Tapped`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_Tapped) event handle of `GridView` and put the code snippet inside. When click on the `GridView` , it will be invoked. If you want it is not be invoked when `ItemClick` event is invoking you could simply use a "flag" to control this. For example:

```
<GridView
    x:Name="gridView" 
    IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
    ItemClick="girdView_ItemClick"
    Background="Azure" 
   Tapped="gridView_Tapped">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate> 
    ...
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
private int flag=0;
private async void girdView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
   var gridView = sender as GridView;
   if (e.ClickedItem == gridView.SelectedItem)
   {

       gridView.SelectedItem = null; 
   }
   flag = 1; 
} 

private void gridView_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (flag == 0)
   {
       var gridView = sender as GridView;
       gridView.SelectedItem = null;
       gridView.SelectedIndex = -1; 
   }
   else
   {
       flag = 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Haha, thank you very much, I also think `gridView_Tapped` should be used, but I don't know how. Now I got it. thanks very much